# Extract colored text out of image

Tags: node.js, image-processing, ocr

I do have an image with white and blue text on it, would it be possible to only extract the blue text out of it using OCR? I'm not interested in the white text.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a sample image that you are working with? What is the background color of the image?

Comment: I'll update my question with my solution shortly. In a nutshell I've determined the RGB color of the blue text and replaced all other pixels with black pixels, resulting in a picture where only the blue text was left. Performing OCR with tesseract delivers good results so far.